# How to append new argument after executing parse_args() for argparse in python?

Tags: python, argparse

I want to use argeparse module in following way,

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-b', dest='binKey', type=str)
args   = parser.parse_args()

# I will make use of args.binKey option in this space
print args.binKey
# After that I want to add -d option to the arguments

parser.add_argument('-d', dest='dir', type=str)
args   = parser.parse_args()
```

With this example, I can only provide -b option as shown below in the help text.

```
$$ python test.py -h
usage: test.py [-h] [-b BINKEY]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -b BINKEY
```

What I want is I should be able to provide both options while running this code and those options should also by visible in --help option

**NOTE:** I know that I can provide both options before executing `parse_args()` once, but that is not the way I want to use my parser.

Comment: You are not supposed to call `parse_args()` for each argument. You `add` all arguments at once, and then call `parse_args()` **once** after you defined all of them... Try going over the [Argparse Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html#id1) to better understand how to use it

Comment: @Tomerikoo I want it in that way actually. I have defined ArgumentParser() object in other module and that object is imported in some other modules(to provide options for conditional statements). 
I want to make use of that already defined object and add customized extra arguments for the script I am using.

Comment: This sounds odd but you would have to make sure that `parse_args` is only called after you added all arguments you need

Comment: You can call `parse_args` multiple times (though a `parse_known_args` may be safer).  But a `-h` will be caught by the first call (and exit).  You could turn off the `help` when setting up the `parser` and add the '-h' argument yourself later.

Comment: @hpaulj, You are right. Could you help newbies like us writing an answer to that? I mean with more details like how to add help option later etc.

Comment: There's a documented `help` action class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the help from @hpaulj's comment, here is the resolution:

- Turn off help option while creating `ArgumentParser` object.
- You can call `parse_known_args` multiple times in between.
- Add help option at the end.

Below is a snippet of the code

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
parser = ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser.add_argument('-b', dest='binKey', type=str)
args   = parser.parse_known_args()[0]

# Here you can make use of args.binKey option in this space
print args.binKey
# You can more options after this as

parser.add_argument('-d', dest='dir', type=str)
parser.add_argument('-h', '--help', action='help', default='==SUPPRESS==', help=('show this help message and exit'))
args   = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to provide both options while running the code you just need to add

```py
parser.add_argument('-d', dest='dir', type=str)
```

before you execute `parse_args()`. If this doesn't solve your problem then you need to more explicitly explain why you need to add the argument afterwards.

Comment: I have defined ArgumentParser() object in other module and that object is imported in some other modules(to provide options for conditional statements). I want to make use of that already declared ArgumentParser() object and add customized extra add_argument() for the script I am using. Having said that I have to make sure that I can make use of default options of old arguments before adding newer one. That is why I was executing parse_args() twice